# What percentage decrease in AIC is significant?

Tags: aic

I have two models with AIC values 2500 and 2590.

So....  Is that significant?  What percentage decrease is usually considered significant?

Answer (score 3):

AICs are not measured on a multiplicative scale, but on an additive one. In addition, the constant offset is not overly important, so it is sometimes implemented differently.

You need to look at *additive* differences between AICs. In your case, one model has an AIC that is $90$ below the other's. That is very strong evidence that the model with the smaller AIC is a better description of the data. You'd come to exactly the same conclusion if the one model's AIC were $-120$ and the other's $-30$.

Typically, you'd say that an AIC difference $\Delta\text{AIC}<2$ is little evidence, $2\leq\Delta\text{AIC}<5$ is weak evidence, $5\leq\Delta\text{AIC}<10$ is medium evidence and $10\leq\Delta\text{AIC}$ is strong evidence in favor of the model with the lower AIC value.

For more information, see Burnham & Anderson, *Model Selection and Multi-Model Inference: A Practical Information-Theoretic Approach*, and [Burnham & Anderson, "Multimodel Inference: Understanding AIC and BIC in Model Selection" (2004, *Sociological Methods & Research*)](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0049124104268644).